# How to customize error messages in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my code:

```
public function store(Request $request){

    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'content' => 'required|min:10',
    ]);

    $new_array = array();
    $new_array['name'] = $request->name;
    $new_array['email'] = $request->email;
    $new_array['content'] = $request->content;
    contact::create($new_array);

    return back();
}
```

Now I need to set some new error-messages for those filters *(ex: `required`, `email`, ..)*.

Currently, this is the default error message for `required`:

> The name field is required.

How can I change it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow this :
View :

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    {{Form::label('Deposit Amount')}}
    {{Form::text('deposit_amount',Input::old('deposit_amount'),array('class'=>"form-control"))}}
    <span class="error">{!!$errors->first('deposit_amount')!!}</span>
    </div>
```

Controller

```
 use App\Http\Requests;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
    use DB;
    use Hash;
    use Auth;
    use App\PaymentModel;
    use Redirect;
    use Response;

class TransactionController extends Controller
{
  public function payment(Request $request){

   $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),  PaymentModel::Rules(), PaymentModel::$message);
   if ($validator->fails())
   {
      return \Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
  }
  else
  {

    $deposit_amount=Input::get("deposit_amount");

    $obj = new PaymentModel();

    $obj->deposit_amount=$deposit_amount;

    if ($obj->save()) {

        Session::flash('success', 'Saved Successfully !!');

    } else {
      Session::flash('error', 'Some thing went wrong!!');
    }

    }

    return Redirect::action('TransactionController@payment');
  }
  }
```

Model

```
   public static function Rules(){
         $rules= array(
        'deposit_amount'=>'required|numeric',       
        ); 
       return $rules;
    }

     public static  $messages=array(
         'deposit_amount.required'=>'Please Enter Amount ',
        'deposit_amount.numeric'=>'Deposit Amount Must be a number ', 
        );
```

Answer (score 10):

You can create a Laravel Request for handling the validations using following command

```
php artisan make:request RequestName
```

You will find the file in app\Http\Request

Inside the file you will find the rules() function where you can mentioned all rules

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
        ];
    }
```

You can create message() function for custom message like

```
 public function messages()
    {
        return[
            'name.required' => 'The name field is required.'
        ];
    }
```

Add this request in controller method

```
public function methodName(RequestName $request)
    {
       //Your code
    }
```

Comment: and then how can I apply `RequestName` ?

Comment: When I submit the form, I am getting: ReflectionException Class App\Http\Controllers\SociallinkRequest does not exist. 
If I add "use App\Http\Requests\SociallinkRequest;" in the App\Http\Requests\SociallinkRequest.php, at the top, then I am getting: HttpException This action is unauthorized.

I am on LV 5.4.

Comment: add `use App\Http\Requests\SociallinkRequest` in your controller

Comment: I was using that. Resolved the issue by returning true from authorize() instead of the default false. Everything started working.

Answer (score 9):

Crate rules

```
public function user_registration_rules(array $data)
{
  $messages = [
    'full-name.required' => 'Please enter full name',     
    'address.required' => 'Please enter address'
  ];

  $validator = Validator::make($data, [
    'full-name' => 'required|min:5|max:70', 
    'address' => 'required'     
  ], $messages);

  return $validator;
}
```

Use in controller like this

```
$validator = $this->user_registration_rules($request_data);   
if($validator->fails())
{
  return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
}
```

Comment: should I write `user_registration_rules()` function in where? in the *request* folder?

Answer (score 2):

From the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#customizing-the-error-messages

You may customize the error messages used by the form request by overriding the messages method. This method should return an array of attribute / rule pairs and their corresponding error messages:

```
/**
 * Get the error messages for the defined validation rules.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function messages() 
{
    return [
    'title.required' => 'A title is required',
    'body.required'  => 'A message is required',
];
}
```

And this is just a copy paste from the docs. You should refer to laravel docs, they are one of the best laid out docs.

Comment: well I'm newbie in Laraver, so I don't know how should I use your code. also I seen that before in the documentation, but still I don't know how exactly should I implement it.

Comment: You might want to go through this free course on laracasts. https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals

Comment: add your code to the request class which you generate through:  php artisan make:request MyRequest 

then go to your controller and replace Request with MyRequest in the parameter of store(Request $request) method or whatever

Comment: OK, but where exactly should it be placed?

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the validator like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'content' => 'required|min:10',
        ]);
```

Now you will be able to catch the validation errors with this :

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    $error_message = $validator->errors()->all();
    // Write Custom Validator Error Message according to the $error_message found.
}
```

Laravel Validator gives pretty comprehensive error messages anyway.

Comment: Can you please assign a error message as test? for example this message should be for `required` filter: `you must write something in this input`

Comment: Just return whatever you require from that. 
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return "you must write something in this input";
}